# Make custom payment using paypal without going through checkout process Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, paypal

I have a out of the box requirement and I don't know where to start.So I was expecting if someone here could give a kickstart.

**What I am trying to build?**

I am trying to do the payment to paypal from the magento 2 store but without going through the checkout process.Like let's take an example "Customer needs to pay for registration or take subscription".For this we could take customer through whole checkout process.

**What I understood in Magento?**

The default payment could be made through checkout process.But we need to consider the subscription as a product. But In my case I can't create it as a product.

**So what best way I could think of achieving this?**

If I could create a custom module which pass the required information to paypal and receive the response from paypal I could successfully create a custom payment which we do normally on core when we need to create payment method.

**What am I looking into?**

I am studying how paypal is being implemented on projects done on core PHP, I am hoping I could get some idea from it.

**What am I expecting from you?**

I am expecting if someone with this kind of experience could show me the correct direction to follow, if there is any other better alternative. I am also confused how i can implement as a modular basis as in magento so if someone could provide some information on that too than that would be great.

I wish I could add some code snippets but it is the initial phase so I am trying to create a thought model and fix the approach that i should follow before starting to code.

Comment: U r looking for Membership Subscription/Reward Points/Loyalty Points Module i think. If u don't wanna use Paypal then which other Payment Method u would like to use?

Comment: not that I am just giving an example, that requirement would also have the same kind of flow right? But if i could know that way I could implement on my own.

Comment: First: Define your Logic Flow. What exactly u want to implement. I think still ur requirement is not clear.

Comment: I think I am preety clear, I want to create a module. It could be anywhere and require a button which takes me to paypal for the payment.I could manage other additinal required parameters for paypal, I just want to know how to achieve this.

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule This is the Sample Module Code  U can Download  & Use. Try to Enable Paypal Express Checkout Button Which Can Display on Mini Cart As well. Let me know if anything needed

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for the link but there are better alternative for sample module creation, you may be aware of  mage2gen.com .Creating module is not my problem I just want to know if the approach that I am following is the best one or is there any other better approach to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I also wish to implement the same